# Dr. Stone making Acetone from Seashells and Wood vinegar

Tags: organic-chemistry

Could you make Acetone from boiling seashells and wood vinegar as said in Dr. Stone? I haven't found anything online that says whether or not it will work.

[image]

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/61408/chalk-and-vinegar  https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/12250/why-is-it-acetone

Comment: Isn't that making acetone from acetic acid and calcium carbonate not methanol and calcium carbonate

Comment: No, it's not. https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/143645/make-acetic-acid-from-wood

Comment: I think I'll try this in real life to test it out. I believe Dr. Stone uses the acetic acid contained in the wood vinegar and reacts it with the seashells to make acetone as you described. Thanks a lot @Mithoron.

Comment: Who is Dr. Stone and why is it related to Chemistry? Am I missing something?

Comment: Dr. Stone is a manga and now anime which has a lot of science in it

Comment: If calcium carbonate is reacted with acetic acid, this mixture produced a solution of calcium acetate. If now this solution is evaporated, the solvant water will disappear and pure calcium acetate is obtained. And if calcium acetate is pyrolized, ift produce acetone according to the following equation $$\ce{Ca(CH3COO)2 -> CH3COCH3 + CaCO3}$$. This is the way acetone was produced for the first time in History. And this is even the reason why acetone got this name instead of the correct propanone.  The word "acetone" comes from "acetate" in a time where the organic chemistry was in infancy.

Comment: Yea I know you can make acetone from acetic acid, but I didn't know there was acetic acid in wood vinegar so I thought the wood vinegar was just methanol